# compare number to multiple comparison operators and values

Tags: r, string, dataframe, data.table, subset

I have to see whether a list of values falls within ranges of values and then assign a particular values. I want to find a way to do this without having to use nested `ifelse()` statements (just learned `ifelse` can't nest more than 51 times and looks soo terrible.).

Since this is a contrived example, I'm wondering if there's a generalizable way to do this (e.g. loop? *apply)? I'm thinking something to do with `paste(eval())` but can't get it to work. Thanks in advance.

```
set.seed(2222)
comparison_table = data.frame(
  lower_comp = c('>=', '>=', '>='),
  upper_comp = c('<', '<', '<'),
  lower_value = c(3, 33, 100),
  upper_value = c(31, 40, 120),
  new_value = c(1, 2, 3)
)

df = data.frame(
  value = runif(n = 25, min = 1, max = 130)
)

df$new_value = with(df, 
  ifelse(value >= 3 & value < 33, 1,
  ifelse(value >= 33 & value < 100, 2, 
  ifelse(value >= 100 & value < 120, 3, NA))))

value            new_value
48.427905        NA
24.461992        1
107.576807       3
76.461703        NA
124.694209       NA
14.132063        1
98.638509        NA
32.436195        NA
88.470441        NA
9.095131         1
49.548878        NA
85.647608        NA
75.357280        NA
120.696858       NA
113.347924       3
51.364939        NA
126.896975       NA
128.282762       NA
115.333414       3
75.022578        NA
128.170932       NA
2.200451         NA
24.085131        1
99.672971        NA
24.945700        1
```

Comment: If your lower_comp and upper_comp columns always take the same values, there's `library(data.table); setDT(df); df[comparison_table, on=.(value >= lower_value, value < upper_value), new_value := i.new_value ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cut()` to split your value vector up:

```
df$new_value <- cut(df$value, breaks= c(3,33,100,120),labels=FALSE, right = FALSE)
```

This defines three intervals (anything outside will default to `NA`):

```
[3,33)
[33,100)
[100,120)
```

Use `right = FALSE` to make the left-hand side inclusive: default is `(x, y]` and we want `[x, y)`.

Comment: thanks for the help. this definitely works for the case i put up. i messed up and didn't realize that the intervals 'ordered' i updated the question. i have been trying to come up with a solution that will allow me to `paste` a string with the conditions that i need and evaluate that with the data.frame: `df$new_value[parse(eval(text = paste0('value >= 3'))] = 1` to this part of the code compact.....

Comment: @bringtheheat In that case I would write a little wrapper function around `cut()` checking your input inequality with `grepl(">=",  comparison_table$lower_comp)`, and say if `TRUE` then `right <- FALSE`, else `right <- TRUE`. Then take a list of your breaks `unique(c(comparison_table$lower_value,comparison_table$upper_value))` to pass to `breaks`. This of course only works if your inequalities are uniform, i.e. you're following ">= and <" or "> and <=".

Comment: @bringtheheat In practice I wouldn't format the comparison table like you have. I'd just have two columns, one for the breaks, and one to define whether it's a left or right hand interval.

Comment: thanks! yea, i wasn't all that great with the's clarity. the issue i'm running into is that the conditional statement is structured (i.e. 2 numbers) but the operators may differ and aren't consecutive. i included the operators since my first thought was some how pasting together the conditional statement and evaluating......i'll have to re-write the question with better specifics. thanks for the `cut` method, thats a really useful way to do comparisons. i have a vague memory of using it with ggplot at some point and forgot about it.